# Classification and regression trees with correlated covariates and a rare event outcome

Tags: logistic, classification, binary-data, multicollinearity, rare-events

I have a small data set (140 observations) which is quite unbalanced (5% of 1's) with an independent binary variable Y and a set of correlated covariates X1,…,Xp. My primary goal is: let’s suppose we have covariate X1, which yields an OR=2.0, and X3, which yields OR 1.6.  My goal is to test whether X1+X3 risk sig. different from 1.8 (the average risk). This is an example with the additive interaction between two covariates, but I am interested in any level of interaction, ie. additive interactions between 3, 4, 5,… covariates.

What analysis do you think I can use?
I was thinking first in a classical logistic regression using a selection of uncorrelated covariates and adding interaction terms, but I found that even with a moderate number of covariates, it is typically difficult to examine all possible interactions with standard regression techniques, because estimating a large number of parameters is required, and model selection quickly becomes cumbersome. Furthermore, risk factors are often correlated, which results in collinearity problems.

Later I though in a non-parametric solution like classification and regression trees but the problem is that is a rare event (Y has just 5% of  the values as 1), so CART doesn’t work well in that framework.